# Could not store data in state in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a two data in cardTypeData :

```
0: {id: 226, obj: {…}, Slug: 'hello-0'
1: {id: 228, obj: {…}, Slug: 'hello-1'}
```

---

```
useEffect(() => {
      let newcard = [];
      console.log("cardTypeData= ",cardTypeData)
          if (cardTypeData) {
            cardTypeData.map((item) => {
              if(item.Slug){
              const requestUrl = `chartconfig/${item.Slug}/${
                searchQuery?.year
                  ? `?year=${searchQuery.year}${
                      searchQuery.month ? "&month=" + searchQuery.month : ""
                    }`
                  : ``
              }`;
              axiosRequest.get(requestUrl)
              .then((res) => {
                  newcard.push(res.data);
              })
              .catch(console.log('err'))
              // .catch((error)=>{
              //   console.log(error)
              // });
            }
            });
          }
          console.log('list', newcard)
          setCardData(newcard);
      }, [cardTypeData]);
```

the console output is shown in the figure,
how to fix this issues.
[image]

[image]

here data is shown but i could not display it in html.

Comment: Please format your code and include render method as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network request is asynhcronous. Before `newcard.push(res.data)` runs, `setCardData(newcard)` is already executed with initialized value of newcard which is [ ], ...you can modify the code something similar as below to make it work

```
useEffect(() => {
      // let newcard = [];
      console.log("cardTypeData= ",cardTypeData)
          if (cardTypeData) {
            cardTypeData.map((item) => {
              if(item.Slug){
              const requestUrl = `chartconfig/${item.Slug}/${
                searchQuery?.year
                  ? `?year=${searchQuery.year}${
                      searchQuery.month ? "&month=" + searchQuery.month : ""
                    }`
                  : ``
              }`;
              axiosRequest.get(requestUrl)
              .then((res) => {
                   
                  ***** modified *****
                  // newcard.push(res.data);
                  setCardData(prev => [...prev, res.data])
              })
              .catch(console.log('err'))
              // .catch((error)=>{
              //   console.log(error)
              // });
            }
            });
          }
          console.log('list', newcard)
          // setCardData(newcard);
      }, [cardTypeData]);
```

Comment: i'm glad it helped.

Comment: while going to next page from this page and returning back brings more data, i mean while comming back to this page i am getting double data .

Answer (score 2):

Refactor, refactor, and refactor again.
The above solutions overall work as expected, but could be written better.
I hope you do not mind if I show you how it should look like.

```
function loadNewCards() {
  if (!cardTypeData) return

  cardTypeData.forEach(async (cardItem) => {
    if (!cardItem.Slug) return

    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(searchQuery).toString()
    const requestUrl = `chartconfig/${cardItem.Slug}/${searchParams}`
    const response = await axios.get(requestUrl).catch(console.log)

    if (!response) return

    setCardData(prevCardData => [...prevCardData, response.data])
  })
}

useEffect(() => {
  loadNewCards()
}, [cardTypeData])
```

Firstly, please avoid nesting. It makes your code less readable.
Try to use negation to avoid nested if / else statement.

```
if (!cardItem.Slug) return
```

would be better than

```
if (item.Slug) {
   const requestUrl = `chartconfig/${item.Slug}`
```

Secondly, please use URLSearchParams to build the query params.
This class will handle your object that contains `year` and `month`.
I think it is better to have

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(searchQuery).toString()
const requestUrl = `chartconfig/${cardItem.Slug}/${searchParams}`
```

instead of

```
const requestUrl = `chartconfig/${item.Slug}/${
  searchQuery?.year
    ? `?year=${searchQuery.year}${
      searchQuery.month ? '&month=' + searchQuery.month : ''
    }`
    : ``
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

I've read somewhere that console.log doesn't always run the exact time you call it, ***sometimes it waits a bit*** especially when you expand the input.

The problem might be from the api calls from the cardTypeData.map.

Try using [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) instead to test it out. Also you will have to extract the async part because React doesn't like async useEffect..

Something like this:

```
const loadNewCards = async () => {
let newcard = [];
console.log("cardTypeData= ", cardTypeData);
if (cardTypeData) {
    for (let item of cardTypeData) {
  if (!item.Slug) {
    const requestUrl = `chartconfig/${item.Slug}/${
      searchQuery?.year
        ? `?year=${searchQuery.year}${
            searchQuery.month ? "&month=" + searchQuery.month : ""
          }`
        : ``
    }`;
    await axiosRequest
      .get(requestUrl)
      .then((res) => {
        newcard.push(res.data);
      })
      .catch(console.log("err"));
  }
}
}
console.log("list", newcard);
setCardData(newcard);
};
useEffect(() => {
    loadNewCards();
}, [cardTypeData]);
```

And if you worried about performance you should use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to run all the calls in parallel.

Comment: thank you bro for your effort to help me out!